# PDO query problem

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am updating some code from the old mysql_* functions to PDO.  It connects without a problem, runs the query without a problem, but the resultset is empty.  PDO::query() is supposed to return a PDOStatement object, yet I am getting true in return.  No errors are reported.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass");
    $stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM report_clientinfo");
    $stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}


echo gettype($stmt) . "\n";
if ($stmt) echo "true\n";
else echo "false\n";

$resultset = $stmt->fetchAll();

if(empty($resultset))
{
    exit("ERROR: getClientInfo query failed.");
}

$DB = null;

print_r($resultset);
```

The output I am seeing is:

object
true
ERROR: getClientInfo query failed.

Any ideas why it is not returning any results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
object  
true  
ERROR: getClientInfo query failed.
```

It looks to me like your `PDOStatement $stmt` variable is in fact reported to be an object, not "`true`".  The code then prints "`true`" when it sees that `$stmt` is non-null, which it is, because it's an object.

I recommend that you check the return value from `$stmt->execute()`.  You might have an SQL error.  For example, if you misspelled the table name, or the table doesn't exist in the database "`dbname`" that you connected to, or the user you login as doesn't have privilege to query that table.

Also check [`$stmt->errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) to get more details on any error that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little embarrassed to report back that I was pointing to the wrong DSN.  I guess that's what I get for trying to learn something new on just a few hours of sleep after going out for New Year's Eve.  Thanks for the tip on the PDOStatement::errorInfo() method, I had not noticed it before.

Comment: No problem.  On just a few hours sleep, it's hard to do anything well  -- except sleeping!